# Error using cell2mat Matlab

Tags: matlab, cell

I have the cell below:

```
 aa={[1.0094]}     {[1.0370]}    {[1.0956]}    {[1.0957]}   {[1.0171]}    
     {[1.0362]}    {[1.1355]}    {[1.0503]}    {[1.5280]}   {[1.1928]}
     {[1.0148]}    {[0.9822]}    {[1.0316]}    {[1.1135]}   {[1.1135]}
```

I used the command cell2mat as below:

```
  aa=cell2mat(aa);
```

but it gives me the error below:

```
 Error using cell2mat (line 45)
 All contents of the input cell array must be of the same data type.
```

any idea what to do?
Best

Comment: Can you provide an exact definition for the cell array `aa` so we can replicate the error message? See the StackOverflow documentation on how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What does `unique(cellfun(@class,aa,'un',0))` give you?

Comment: @SardarUsama: ans =

  2×1 cell array

    {'cell'  }
    {'double'}

Comment: As verbatross asked you in the first comment, create an example of cell array that depicts your actual data like above. Also provide your required output for that example. Which version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: I think another relevant question is: how was this cell array created? Do you control the code that generates it? If so, I would suggest that you change it to generate a more sensible output, such as a plain numeric array.

Comment: @SardarUsama @ CrisLeungo  The data is created and saved in such structure before I arrive in the lab. I just have given data, I don't know how did it generate. I used MATLAB 2017b.

Comment: @SardarUsama example how array generated? I don't know. I just received the structure.  provide required output: a cell that I can convert to mat using cell2mat, I use MATLAB 2017b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aa = { {[1.0094]}    {[1.0370]}    {[1.0956]}    {[1.0957]}   {[1.0171]}  ...  
       {[1.0362]}    {[1.1355]}    {[1.0503]}    {[1.5280]}   {[1.1928]}  ...
       {[1.0148]}    {[0.9822]}    {[1.0316]}    {[1.1135]}   {[1.1135]} };
```

is a cell array containing cell arrays.

```
>> % Proof:
>> aa(1)

ans =

  1×1 cell array

    {1×1 cell}
```

Unfortunately [`cell2mat()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) does not support cell arrays containing cell arrays or objects.

[As the documentation of `cell2mat` states:](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html#bufa81t-2)

> #### Input Arguments
>
> > ```
> > C — Input cell array
> >     cell array
> > ```
>
> Input cell array, in which all cells contain the same data type.
>   `cell2mat` accepts numeric or character data within cells of `C`, or
>   structures with the same field names and data types. **`cell2mat` does not
>   accept objects or nested cells within `C`**.

A workaround could be to convert all elements inside `aa` into doubles, and later call `cell2mat()`

```
bb = zeros(1, length(aa));         % Initialize new vector to hold converted cells
for i = 1:length(aa)               % For all elements in aa
    bb(i) = cell2mat(aa{1, i});    % Convert them
end
% Now bb is an array of doubles
%
% bb =
%
%  Columns 1 through 12
%
%    1.0094    1.0370    1.0956    1.0957    1.0171    1.0362    1.1355    1.0503    1.5280    1.1928    1.0148    0.9822
%
%  Columns 13 through 15
%
%    1.0316    1.1135    1.1135
```

Comment: This is not the same definition of `aa` as the OP is using. Running `cell2mat(aa)` on using this definition produces the error: `Error using cell2mat (line 52):
CELL2MAT does not support cell arrays containing cell arrays or objects`, which is different from the stated error.

Comment: you are right. What is the solution now?

Comment: @verbatross :  Yes, I could see it is not the same error. But I have cell arrays contains cell(1x1) cell arrays and I need to write it as mat file. Do you have any solution what to do?

Comment: @Marco It is not necessarily a cell array containing cell arrays. TMW changed the view of cell arrays in R2017b.

Comment: @Sonia we can't help properly until you've provided an exact definition for `aa` so we can replicate the error. If you edit the question accordingly there are many people here who can help. For the definition of `aa` used in this example (a cell array containing 1x1 cell arrays containing numeric scalars), a solution is: `aa = cellfun(@(x)x{1}, aa);`.